# Date class for Budgeting App

Tags: c++, datetime, library

This is a Date class I made for a hobby project. It does not deal with time at all; that is, the smallest unit of time it considers is one day, and no concern with time zones.

Where I do most of my coding, I'm not allowed C++11, so if there are any new languages features that would apply here, I am definitely interested in hearing about it. I'd also like to hear about the overall design of the class, or any edge cases I may have missed.

Date.h

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <time.h>

/**
 * Represents a date. Does not account for time. Does not account for time zones
 */
class Date
{
public:
    /**
     * @brief Construct current, local Date
     */
    Date();

    /**
     * @brief Construct local Date from timestamp
     * @param timestamp seconds since January 1 1970 UTC
     */
    Date(time_t timestamp);

    /**
     * Return the year
     */
    size_t getYear() const;

    /**
     * @brief Return a number representing the month.
     *
     * @return represented month
     */
    size_t getMonth() const;

    /**
     * @brief get name of month, in English
     */
    std::string getMonthString() const;

    /**
     * @brief get day of month
     */
    size_t getDate() const;

    /**
     * @brief Increment current date by given number of years.
     */
    void addYears(int numberOfYears);

    /**
     * @brief Increment current date by given number of months.
     */
    void addMonths(int numberOfMonths);

    /**
     * @brief Increment current date by given number of days.
     */
    void addDays(int numberOfDays);

    /**
     * @brief return String representation of date
     * example: 1 February 1983
     */
    std::string toString() const;

    bool operator==(const Date& rhs) const;
    bool operator!=(const Date& rhs) const;

private:
    bool isLeapYear(size_t year) const;
    bool isLeapYear() const;
    void init(time_t timestamp);
    const static std::vector<std::string> monthNames;
    size_t daysPerMonth() const;

    int date;
    int month;
    int year;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Date& rhs);
```

Date.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Date.h"
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>

Date::Date()
{
    init(time(NULL));
}

Date::Date(time_t timestamp)
{
    init(timestamp);
}

void Date::init(time_t timestamp)
{
    struct tm datetime;
    localtime_s(&datetime, &timestamp);
    year = datetime.tm_year + 1900;
    month = datetime.tm_mon;
    date = datetime.tm_mday;
}

size_t Date::getYear() const
{
    return year;
}

size_t Date::getMonth() const
{
    //1-index for human use
    return month + 1;
}

size_t Date::getDate() const
{
    return date;
}

std::string Date::toString() const
{
    return std::to_string(getDate()) + " " + getMonthString() + " " + std::to_string(getYear());
}

const std::vector<std::string> Date::monthNames = {
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December"
};

std::string Date::getMonthString() const
{
    return monthNames[getMonth()];
}

bool Date::operator==(const Date& rhs) const
{
    return getYear() == rhs.getYear() &&
        getMonth() == rhs.getMonth() &&
        getDate() == rhs.getDate();
}

bool Date::operator!=(const Date& rhs) const
{
    return !(*this == rhs);
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Date& rhs)
{
    return stream << rhs.toString();
}

void Date::addYears(int numberOfYears)
{
    if (isLeapYear() &&
        !isLeapYear(getYear() + numberOfYears) && 
        date == 29)
    {
        addDays(1);
    }
    year += numberOfYears;
}

void Date::addDays(int numberOfDays)
{
    numberOfDays += (date - 1);
    date = 1;

    while (numberOfDays < 0)
    {
        addMonths(-1);
        numberOfDays += daysPerMonth();
    }
    while (numberOfDays >= daysPerMonth())
    {
        numberOfDays -= daysPerMonth();
        addMonths(1);
    }
    date += numberOfDays;

}

void Date::addMonths(int numberOfMonths)
{
    month += numberOfMonths;
    while (month < 0)
    {
        addYears(-1);
        month += 12;
    }
    while (month > 11)
    {
        addYears(1);
        month -= 12;
    }
    if (date > daysPerMonth())
    {
        // No need to be precise. Just loop to the 1st.
        month += 1;
        date = 1;
    }
}

size_t Date::daysPerMonth() const
{
    assert(month >= 0);
    assert(month <= 11);
    switch (month)
    {
    case 0:
    case 2:
    case 4:
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 9:
    case 11:
        return 31;
    case 3:
    case 5:
    case 8:
        return 30;
    default: //February
        if (isLeapYear())
        {
            return 29;
        }
        return 28;
    }
}

bool Date::isLeapYear(size_t year) const
{
    return year % 4 == 0;
}

bool Date::isLeapYear() const
{
    return isLeapYear(getYear());
}
```

Comment: The leap year calculation is more complicated than that. Years that are multiples of 100 aren't leap years except multiples of 400 are.

Comment: Ugh, of course it is. Good catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Design

#### Member (private) vs. Non Member

Allways try to keep your Class small. Functions like `isLeapYear(size_t year)` or `getDaysPerMonth()` do not really operate on the State of your class. Thus you should consider to make them non-member functions. 
I would than suggest to only declare and define them in the *.cpp (within a [anonymous namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357404/why-are-unnamed-namespaces-used-and-what-are-their-benefits) perhaps) that would lessen the compile dependencies.

Same for the variable monthNames.

#### Function names

When I read the function name `getDate()` in a Class `Date` I would think that it returns something like a copy or different representation of the whole Class. Consider to rename the Function.

## Coding style

#### Named loops

Loops like

```
while (month > 11)
{
    addYears(1);
    month -= 12;
}
```

take a little time and effort to understand. Consider to move them in seperate named functions like "getNumberOfYearsFromAmountOfDays(...)". In this way it is much easier to understand the code on first sight.
I would make these functions non-member.

## Bug

#### IsLeapYear

From the comments:

"The leap year calculation is more complicated than that. Years that are multiples of 100 aren't leap years except multiples of 400 are." – RichN

## C++11

One thing I see you could change with C++11 is the `init` Function. Because it is now allowed to call one Constructor in the initializer list from another.
Example

```
Date::Date() :
   Date(time(NULL))
{
   /* empty */
}
```

Thats all. Its not much but perhaps it helps a little.